# How to remove decimal value in PHP?

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to remove decimal value

my value: `1277902800000.0`

I have tried `round(1277902800000.0)` it doesn't work for me

> Found Answer My local machine run 32bt config it is the problem.

Comment: try `floor(1277902800000.0)`

Comment: `number_format($number, 0, ".", "");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

number_format(1277902800000.0)

Reference http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

Answer (score 0):

use below function for remove decimal value in PHP.

```
<?php
echo round(1277902800000.0); // Round the number, this example would echo 1277902800000.
echo '<br />';
echo floor(1277902800000.0); // Round down, this would echo 1277902800000.
echo '<br />';
echo ceil(1277902800000.0); // Round up, this would be 1277902800000.
?>
```

Comment: tried everything.

Comment: @deepak try echo (int)1277902800000.0;

Comment: `echo (int)1277902800000.0;` gives `-1997454208`

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [`floor()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.floor.php) function

```
floor(1277902800000.0)
```